# How to make these banner icons on Photoshop?

Tags: icons, photoshop, banner

[image]

How the steps I need to follow to make these banners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can make those banners in Photoshop, they appear to be vector images. adobe Illustrator might be the program you are looking for. when you create a vector image it can be re-sized at any time without damaging pixels, since it's vector. If you would like i would gladly make a short tutorial on how to make similar banners in adobe illustrator and upload them to my personal YouTube Channel. for now a useful sight that contains similar tutorials is http://vector.tutsplus.com/ -Jacob

Comment: sorry i got behind with work recently. i will do this for the new year. then i will post the link here.